# Datepicker with dynamically blocked dates from DB using AngularJS and PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, datepicker

I've been scanning the internet for a datepicker that checks in a DB if dates are available or not in the current month, but to my surprise haven't found one! Does anyone know of an datepicker like this? Or any suggestions of a AngularJS datepicker that I can build off of? Hopefully without using jQuery, to not have to include a lib when AngularJS is already loaded.

My idea is that dates in a month are all blocked until that month has been loaded, and when progress bar disappears, available dates are selectable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular datetime picker directive.
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepickerPopup
It proivdes props for disable selected date.
As well as you can use Kendo UI datepicker,
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/angular.
To disable any dates you need to retreive all the dates from the database and initiate datepicker with disable dates properties.

Comment: Hi Tejaswi, thank you for your response! I would need the valid/invalid dates to be fetched dynamically though. When I go to a new month, only then would the DB be checked to see if the dates are enabled or not, to not load tons of dates for a dozen different datepickers on page load.